# Gradient background scaled after resizing ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient

In my app, I have `ConstraitLayout` with a gradient background. In a runtime, this `ConstraitLayout` can be resized. The problem I faced is that gradient drawable "isn't scaled". I will show an image to explain it better:

[image]

In the green circles, You can see that the color before and after resizing at the and of `ConstraitLayout` is different. Is this possible to force an app to set a gradient in the full range of colors?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do it is to set `ConstraitLayout` background every time its changes. I think it is not the best way to do it, especially in my case when `ConstraitLayout` size was changing in on `onTouch` event, so my App has to change it so many times. But I didn't see any problems while using this solution.